# Create Writeable to HTTP response in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I defined a `class` in `models/ResponseQuery` as follows:

```
case class ResponseQuery(
  query: String,
  tableArray: Array[String]
)
```

In a file in `app/controllers/` I return an object of type `responseQuery`

```
var responseQuery: models.ResponseQuery
Future.successful(Ok(responseQuery))
```

However, I get the following error while compiling:

> Cannot write an instance of `models.ResponseQuery` to `HTTP response`.
>    Try to define a `Writeable[models.ResponseQuery]`

I appreciate any help in solving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with companion object to `ResponseQuery` and put implicit format for it.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

object ResponseQuery {
  implicit format = Json.format[ResponseQuery]
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it does? I do not want the ResponseQuery object to be returned as Json to the post request but rather as ResponseQuery object.

Comment: Hmm, I think that you need to have Json here, this format will keep your structure when you will pass it to another place. What do you want to achieve with this object?